# Straight bash empty parameter not recognized

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments

Good day SO!

I'm working on a Django Project for learning purposes. Now I have a little bash script (working properly) to migrate my Django database and create a superuser with a onetoone profile.

Now I want to update my bash script so it recognizes some parameters. For example to automatically run the model migrations (makemigrations) or run the server after successfully migrating the database.

So I want to tell the bash to make migrations before migrating and run the server when finished (keys without values).

```
(venv)edwin@edwin:/project/installs/$ source install_database.sh -m -r
```

Now, I'm quite new to Linux and completely new to Straight Bash Space Separated bash scripts. I've read that using getopt[s] has no use in this case, since it can't handle empty argument strings.

So I attempted to create the Straight Bash Space Separated like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while [[ %# > 1 ]]
do
    key=$1

    case $key in
        -m|--makemigrations)
        MAKEMIGRATIONS=true
        shift
        ;;
        -r|--runserver)
        RUNSERVER=true
        shift
        ;;
        *)
        echo "invalid argument"
        ;;
    esac
shift
done

echo "${RUNSERVER}"
echo "${MAKEMIGRATIONS}"
```

Whatever I attempt to initiate

```
(venv)edwin@edwin:/project/installs/$ source install_database.sh -m -r
(venv)edwin@edwin:/project/installs/$ source install_database.sh -m "test" -r "test"
(venv)edwin@edwin:/project/installs/$ source install_database.sh -m test -r test
```

I keep getting the result

```
false
false
```

Probably it's a beginners mistake, but I can't seem to figure it out...
Can you give me an explanation of what I am doing wrong, and push me in the right direction to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no mention of "False" in your script. Where does it come from? Also, what's `%#`?

Comment: I've been searching the web to find out how to make a bash accept parameters. Which lead me tohttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash/14203146#14203146 I'm not sure how it gets the false, however I thought it might return false on an empty or unset variable? And about %#, I assumed it was some form of counting the amount of parameters.. Which, based on your reaction, is probably a wrong assumption (Note: False = false (lower case, my bad))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three mistakes:

1) `%#` should be `$#`

2) You have two `shift` instructions in case of an accepted key (one inside the `case` and one at the end of the `while` loop). Just remove the `shift`s inside the `case`s and keep the one at the end of the loop (remember you want to shift even if the key is not recognized).

3) `$#` gives you the number of arguments excluding the program's name, so the while loop condition should be `while [[ $# > 0 ]]`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! mistake #1... let's forget about that one? good! Mistake #2 and #3 also applied...  calling (venv)edwin@edwin:/project/installs/$ source install_database.sh with or without -r -m both result in true true? Any idea why?

Comment: @Nrzonline that could be a Mistake #4, but I will not add it because I'm not a bash expert either. Anyway: it is a good idea (if not necessary) to initalize both variables to false before the `while` loop.

Comment: As to #2 the inner `shift`s are correct for the option-accepting versions and incorrect for no-option versions. That's a complication that the script needs to handle internally either by testing the next option for a leading `-` or by requiring the flag value to be "cuddled" to the flag (i.e. not `-r test` but `-rtest`).

Comment: OP wants `-gt 0` not `> 0`. Numeric comparison not string comparison.